# Layout issue when swiped (added space)

Tags: html, css, layout, bootstrap-4

When it loads for the first time, the layout is perfectly aligned. Once you swipe left, this gap appears and won't go away. I used chrome Dev tools and it doesn't seem to have any extra margin or padding (if that's important).

[image: screenshot of my site]

https://codepen.io/iyhui/pen/gOrqyYK

Edit:
added codepen url

```
 body{
    overflow:hidden;
 }
```

Adding `overflow:hidden;` doesn't fix my problem, it causes a new one - i can't scroll anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need .row classes for every section in the website. You only need it when you're using .col classes as the children.

As in your case, simply replacing the top button container into this structure will get rid of the overflow.

```
<div class="text-center">
    <button class="bookButton">
      <i class="far fa-calendar-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> Schedule an appointment
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, always provide your code with your question, so we can get the a better understanding of your problem. Sharing a Codepen or JSFiddle link is very nice.

Some element is overflowing. Check all the elements and find out which one is causing the problem. Adding a **overflow:hidden;** to the body selector will solve your issue. But it is **not the best practice**.

**UPDATE**

Bootstrap has negative margins in its row class. The section which is causing the issue is the "Schedule an Appointment" section. Give its parent a width of 100% or remove the negative margins from the row class or put it in a bootstrap container. Putting rows in a container is a good practice when you are using bootstrap. e.g.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     //your columns
   </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap has many container classes. [check official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/overview/)

Comment: added link! adding overflow:hidden; stops the scrolling feature

Comment: I have edited the answer. Check the stuff written under UPDATE.